# Unable to access few tabs in the openLDAP webui

Tags: openldap

After logging into the openLDAP WebUI, I am unable to access few of the templates, in the webui they are marked with a cross.

[image: openLDAP webui]]

How do I enable them?

Comment: OpenLDAP doesn't have a webui; this must be a third-party app. Is it phpLdapAdmin?

Comment: @grawity: Yes its a phpLdapAdmin, After loggin into it I am unable to access few objects which are cross marked, as mentioned above.

Comment: @grawity: Any suggestion on this, how to resolve so that I can access all the templates?